# Derivative of the integral of $\exp(ax)\over 1+\exp(x)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, leibniz-integral-rule

Given $a\in(0,1)$ I want to prove the function
\begin{align*}
g(a)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\exp(ax)}{1+\exp(x)}dx
\end{align*}
is infinitely differentiable.

I proved the function $f(a,x)=\frac{\exp(ax)}{1+\exp(x)}$ is integrable  (with respect to $x$) for each $a\in(0,1)$, and you can clearly differentiate (with respect to $a$) to obtain $\partial_{a}f(a,x)=x\frac{\exp(ax)}{1+\exp(x)}$.

I would like to conclude by showing there is an integrable function $h$ such that for each $a\in(0,1)$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}, \; h(x)\ge |\partial_{a}f(a,x)|$ but I don't think this last condition is possible. Is there another way to prove the differentiability of $g$?

Any help would be apprecciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: For $x > 0$, $\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} \le e^{(a-1)x}$.

Comment: But since I want the bound to work for every $a\in(0,1)$, that inequality only gives me $\frac{\exp(ax)}{1+\exp(x)} \le 1$, wich later becomes $\partial_{a}f(a,x) \le x$. Doesn't it?

Comment: What can you say about the convergence of $\int_0^\infty xe^{(a-1)x}dx$ when $a \in (0,1)$?

Comment: That it converges. But as far as I understand I need a bound wich does not depend on $a$. I don't get your argument yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an integrable bound which is universal for all $a\in (0,1)$. Differentiability at some $a$ in that interval only depends on the behavior of the function in some neighborhood of $a$. For any such $a$, you can consider the function $g$ on $(a-\varepsilon/2,a+\varepsilon/2)$ with $\varepsilon<a$, $a+\varepsilon<1$. Then, the function

$$
h(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle{x\frac{e^{(a+\varepsilon)x}}{1+e^{x}};\quad x>0}\\
\displaystyle{x\frac{e^{(a-\varepsilon)x}}{1+e^{x}};\quad x<0}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

is an integrable upper bound for $\partial_af$ and you can apply the theorem on differentiation under the (Lebesgue) integral sign to conclude that $g$ is differentiable for $a\in(a-\varepsilon/2,a+\varepsilon/2)$ and its derivative can be found by differentiating under the integral sign. The conclusion is that $g$ is differentiable for each $a\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it :)

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but why is $$f(x)=\frac{e^{(a+\varepsilon)x}}{1+e^{x}}$$ an upper bound? For $x>0$ it increases, but for $x<0$ you decrease the values.

Comment: Well.. $r\to e^r$ is an increasing function, so for any $r\in (a-\varepsilon/2,a+\varepsilon/2)$, $e^{rx}<e^{(a+\varepsilon)x}$

Comment: Actually, you are right. I modified my answer accordingly.